# What is the name of this game with dice and tiles?

Tags: identify-this-game

The person offering it calls it "Bamboo Game".
There are no rules supplied with it.

[image: Bamboo Game]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The name of this game is called "[Shut the Box](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9851/shut-box)". I believe there are one and two player versions of it.

The goal of the game is to obtain the numbers on the tiles through dice rolls, "shutting" the tiles by turning them around.

Comment: Welcome to board and card games Q&A. Great first answer.
I added a link to BGG for additional reference.

Comment: The answer might be improved by quoting/summarizing the rules of the game (briefly explaining how it works).